# what time is necessary to wipe a hdd?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm doing a `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc bs=4096`
The disk is 3Tb.
It's been 14 hours it's running, is it an acceptable timeframe, when can I expect it to finish ? Can I calculate an expected time to process that operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/seven_pass_erase_duration it would take around 16 hours... (250 gig single overwrite in around 79 minutes).

It depends on your Computers speed to create random seed from `/dev/urandom`, your device speed, your port speed.

btw using `/dev/urandom` is not more secure then using `/dev/zero`, which is also faster:

```
root@m2310:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=1024 bs=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00741118 s, 141 MB/s
root@m2310:~# dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.txt count=1024 bs=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.165744 s, 6.3 MB/s
```

Reads with 141 MB/s from `/dev/zero` and 6.4 MB/s from `/dev/urandom`

Comment: and /dev/zero is faster I bet ?

Comment: it is... a test machine read 141 mb/s from /dev/zero and 6.3mb/s from /dev/urandom

Comment: @euri10 use `shred` of coreutils: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shred.1.html ; it can be used on block devices (e.g. `shred -v -n 1 /dev/sdc`, `shred -v -n 0 -z /dev/sdc`)

Comment: @TomYan any idea of the time it takes ?

Comment: @euri10 depends on the sequential write speed of your HDD. with shred the random data generation would not be the bottleneck.